# Partition on a physical disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

How do I tell where my hard drive partition is physically on the drive (i.e. beginning of the disk)? In Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Click `Start` button
- Right click on `Computer`
- Select `Manage`
- Select `Storage` | `Disk Management` from the tree structure on the left

You'll then be shown all the physical drives and partitions with mapped drive letters and other info.

Comment: No, because the actual physical media has 3(4) cylinders and it doesn't show that.

Comment: "cylinders"? You mean platters? Yes that might be the case. But the storage is organized in rings (called cylinders): the outermost track on all the platters comprise the first cylinder; all the way to the innermost track on each platter. So the graphical display on Disk Management does show outermost to innermost allocation. (Not counting sectors which are hot-swapped in.)

Comment: @Ken, yes, that's what I meant. Good to know thanks.